# Angular HttpClient POST sends Request Payload instead of Form Data

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, httpclient

I'm trying to do a post with form data elements (that's what the api supports), but when using the `.post` it sends Request Payload.

If I set the headers to `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` then it sends the entire json as a key with a blank value
What am I doing wrong here ?

```
this.http.post("/auth", {
    uaUserName: this.loginForm.controls.uaUserName.value,
    uaPassword: this.loginForm.controls.uaPassword.value
})
    .subscribe((data: Profile) => {
            this.profileProvider.profile = {...data};
        },
        () => {
        }
    );
```

Example post:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the body I am sending had to be stringified, so I imported `qs` and did `qs.stringify({...})` and it worked.